# What do the white dashes on the Skyrim map represent?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the different symbols on the map represent?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35743/what-do-the-different-symbols-on-the-map-represent)

I can never figure out what the white dashes or ticks on the skyrim compass means, Is it an important NPC?  I checked the page with all of the compass things today and I didn't see a white tick.

Comment: I feel like I know what your talking about, but I can't quite remember. It's been months since I've played Skyrim. Do you maybe have a picture?

Comment: I might be wrong but I'm actually getting the feeling the OP isn't talking about the compass symbols or the arrows. Are you talking about the single | ' ' ' ' | ' ' ' ' | ' ' ' ' | dashes? If so they don't really mean anything - they are just a reference so you can determine how far from a particular point you're facing.

Comment: `that's actually what I'm talking about, so they don't mean anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to white arrows (the most common mark on on the compass), they are quest markers. They depend on which is your current mission and indicates places and/or people important to the quest. For more details, take a lot in this relation:
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Map_Symbols_(Skyrim)

Comment: oh ok, so they are points of interest in regards to an activated quest?

Comment: Follow the arrows to get to your current quest location